# opencv structured forest edge detection and findcontours

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, image-processing, edge-detection, opencv3.0

I am trying to use opencv via visual c++ to extract contours of an image. I was able to do that using the opencv [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) for findcontours. 
findcontours works in two steps

1. Detect edges using canny edge detector.
2. Feed the output of canny to findcontours.

I want to try out the same with '[Structured Forest Edge Detection](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/da5/tutorial_ximgproc_prediction.html#gsc.tab=0)' (Zitnick et al). I am able to extract the edges and display them, but when I try to feed the output to findcontours. I am getting a 'cv::Exception at memory location 0x0020EE9C' error. (see code below). What am I doing wrong?

```
Mat src = imread("image.jpg");

src.convertTo(src, CV_32F, 1.0 / 255.0);

Mat edges(src.size(), src.type());

Ptr<StructuredEdgeDetection> pDollar = createStructuredEdgeDetection("model.yml.gz");

pDollar->detectEdges(src, edges);

findContours(edges, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
```

Comment: I tried converting the edges from CV_32F to CV_8U as follows  `edges.convertTo(edges_cv8u, CV_8U, 255.0 / (max - min), -255.0 / min)` and then passed edges_cv8u into findContours. still the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
pDollar->detectEdges(src, edges);
```

`edges` type is CV_32F. you must convert it to 8-bit single-channel image